# How to store tensors with labels for cnn training

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have tensors that are (3x512x512). I couldn't make a column out of them due to the shape in a pandas dataframe. I want to store the tensors with their respective labels so that I can use them to train a CNN.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly. In the following code, I am simulating that I have tensor of shape `(3, 512, 512)` with its corresponding labels.

```
import torch
data = []
labels = []
for i in range(10):
  x = torch.randn(3, 512, 512)
  data.append(x)
  labels.append(torch.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(1,))[0])
data = torch.stack(data)
labels = torch.tensor(labels)
torch.save({'data': data, 'labels': labels},
           "all_data.pt")
a = torch.load("all_data.pt")
a['data'].shape, a['labels'].shape
```